# Differences between the ruby 2.3 safe operator "&." and CoffeeScript existential operator ".?"

Tags: ruby, syntax, coffeescript

What, if any, are the differences between the ruby 2.3 safe operator `&.` and the CoffeeScript existential operator `.?`

Comment: The new safe operator is `&.`, and it is probably going to be introduced in Ruby 2.2.3

Comment: It's already been announced for 2.3: https://getpocket.com/a/read/1129842696

Comment: Yes, you're right. I misred.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> CoffeeScript's existential operator `?` returns true unless a variable
>   is null or undefined, which makes it analogous to Ruby's nil?

Instead, the new Ruby safe navigation operator `&.` is used to call a method of an `Object` that can be `nil` without raising an exception. If the object is not `nil`, the method will be executed; otherwise, it returns `nil`.

Something like this:

```
obj.try!(:method1).try!(:method2)

if obj && obj.method1
  #...
end
```

becomes:

```
obj&.method1&.method2

if obj&.method1
  #...
end
```

References:

- http://coffeescript.org/#lexical-scope
- https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11537
- http://irb.rocks/ruby-safe-operator/